# Need help changing the color of an SVG in a function - Skycons

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, ecmascript-6

I am working with a weather app based on this [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wPElVpR1rwA)

I have the following [code](https://darkskyapp.github.io/skycons/) and am using Skycons.js

The issue I am having is now I am trying to implement a darkmode in this. and I have most of it functioning, however I cannot find a way to change the Skycon from black to white then back to black when my dark mode toggle is on.

Here is my code :

```
//pulls Skycons from skycons.js

function setIcons(icon, iconID) {
  const skycons = new Skycons({color: "black"});
  const currentIcon = icon.replace(/-/g, "_").toUpperCase();
  skycons.play();
  return skycons.set(iconID, Skycons[currentIcon]);
}

// Dark Mode Toggle Button
function darkMode(obj) {
  if ($(obj).is(":checked")){
    $("body").addClass("dark");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("dark"); 
  }
}
```

Ideally I want to have my button be able to toggle off and on dark mode which should change my SVG to and from white and same for the text and the background from a blue gradient to a purple gradient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code needed to be refactored to include different functions.

```
let currentMode = 'light'

window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  getWeather();
});

function getWeather() {
 if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
```

const long = position.coords.longitude;
      const lat = position.coords.latitude;

```
  const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
  const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/3dfa731ae990c93b6909c90958e9bc36/${lat},${long}`;
  fetch(api)
    .then(response => {
      return response.json();
    })

    .then(data => {
      loadData(data)
    });
});
}
}...
// Dark Mode Toggle Button

function toggleMode(sourceCheckbox) {
  const newMode = currentMode === 'light' ? 'dark' : 'light'
  currentMode = newMode
  getWeather();
  if ($(sourceCheckbox).is(":checked")) {
    $("body").addClass("dark");
  } else {
    $("body").removeClass("dark");

  }
}
```